# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : An error occurred trying to start process 'npm' with working directory '

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core

I'm trying to run my .NET project in Manjaro Linux (in Windows is working perfectly) and I have the next error:

[image]

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.AggregateException
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'One or more errors occurred.'
 Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
 Innermost exception     System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : An error occurred trying to start process 'npm' with working directory '../../My Project'. No such file or directory
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.Npm.NodeScriptRunner.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String commandName)
```

I was researching but I couldn't find a solution. I can see `w32` and maybe I need to change something for Linux but I don't know what.

The directory is not found but the path is OK.
Also I tried escaping the spaces using `My\\ Project` but was not the solution.

Another thing that I tried was give permission to `chmod +x` to the folder and doesn't work.

Any help?

### EDIT

I realized I can see the problem **ONLY** when i'm `debugging` (F5 in VsCode. If in the console I write `dotnet run` works perfectly.
But now I don't know how I will debug...

Comment: I just tested Process.Start and it will not give this error if the working directory doesn't exist. Basically it seems that your problem is that `npm` is not found, it should have nothing to do with your `spa.Options.SourcePath` setting. Apparently `Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeScriptRunner.LaunchNodeProcess` is expecting `npm` to exist somewhere in your system's PATHs but it does not. Reinstalling npm or following asp.net directions for getting it set up should fix a problem like this.

Comment: @Evelyn thanks for your help. I did a `which npm` and the path is `/home/diego/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/npm`. I think is OK and when I execute `npm` in random places always is working except in the project. Any other idea?

Comment: I realized that is only happening when I'm entering in `debug` (F5) in `vsCode`. If I execute `dotnet run` works perfectly. But now I don't know how can I debug if I don't have this option @Evelyn

Comment: Hm I don't know why that may be, maybe debug is setting its own `npm` variable, you could have your program log out `which npm` or whatever to see what it says during debug. Your vscode may be setting variables when debugging and overwriting the npm path.

Comment: Thanks for reply again @Evelyn. I shared my solution in the next message. 
Thanks for your help and try with me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
`npm` was working perfectly in my system but I don't know why in the project has the problem mentioned before.
**I reinstalled `npm` again and now my project works**.

I don't know if the problem was because I installed `npm` before without `sudo` but in the only place that I had this problem was in my project and debugging. Reinstall `npm` as my solution.